# (Ts) can not find name 'parse'

Tags: typescript

Creating ts file and d.ts file in the same directory will give an error：can not find name 'test'

```
// src/index.ts
parse('123123')
// src/index.d.ts
declare var parse: (selector: string) => any;
```

when i change the d.ts file's path,it works fine

```
// src/index.ts
parse('123123')
// src/xxx/index.d.ts
declare var parse: (selector: string) => any;
```

below is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: If you're using VSCode, try command palette: Restart TS Server

Answer (score 0):

The beste way to work with custom typings is to create a directory in your src dir, e.g. typings.

Then you have to point your tsc compiler to that folder by adding the following snippet to your tsconfig file:

```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types",
        "./src/typings"
     ]
   }
   ...
  }
```

Then you can order you typings as a module. Create a directory ./src/typings/parse-module with one file: index.d.ts:

```
declare module "parse-module" {
   export function parse(selector: string): any;
}
```

Now you can import it an happily compile it in your index.ts file:

```
import { parse } from "parse-module";

parse("blabla");
```